# Why is the critic badge awarded if you downvote by accident and then upvote the same answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I accidentally downvoted a question (misclick, drank lots of coffee heh...) and then upvoted the same answer.  I noticed I was award the critic badge for giving my first downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why is it wrong? You indeed cast a downvote.

Whether you revoke it later or not isn't relevant, it was indeed cast for at least  a few minutes (that's how long the badge process takes to run).

Comment: I guess this is a badge that's not "wow a big accomplishment" but rather to encourage exploring the system.  You did explore the system, even if unintentionally.